# Using Sass in rails 3.0.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, sass

i am trying to use sass in a rails 3.0.1 project that i am working on. I install the gem but when i create a scss file and add some style nothing happens. I've been searching for an answer and it seems others have haml installed as well, do I need this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should add the assets pipeline (Sprockets) in addition to SASS.

Here is a gist that explains the setup for Rails 3.0.x.

https://gist.github.com/911003

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that later, decided to leave it for today.